# how to return two list in two variables in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to do this:

```
from collections import deque


def list3_to2(list1, list2, list3):

    Left = []
    Right = []

    q = deque()

    for a, b, c in list1, list2, list3:
        q.append(a)
        q.append(b)
        q.append(c)

    tmp = 1

    while q:
        if tmp % 2 == 0:
            Left.append(q.popleft())
        else:
            Right.append(q.popleft())
        tmp += 1

    return Left, Right

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['d', 'e', 'f']
c = ['g', 'h', 'i']

l, r = list3_to2(a, b, c)
print(l)
print(r)
```

But instead of two lists in result i got four lists.
Output:

```
['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']
['a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i']
['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']
['a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i']
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Basically i need to transform 3 lists into 2 lists using deque with correct order.

Comment: What is `# some code`? What are `a`, `b`, `c`? What does `f` have to do with `list3_to2`?

Comment: This seems to complicated, instead you could just add together all the lists and then slice the resulting in half

Comment: @Chris_Rands than the first list would be `abcde`, not `acegi`, and similarly the second one

Comment: It's a task. I need to do exactly this. I do understand, that it is useless in practice.

Comment: This code seems working to me (https://hastebin.com/epatusalaj.rb)

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the code correct/it is broken?

Answer (score 0):

Thank to everyone. I got it. My function just returning a tuple. That's why i got both lists in varibles l and r. Just need to type `l = list3_to2(a, b, c)[0]` and `r = list3_to2(a, b, c)[1]`